# How to save estimator in Tensorflow for later use?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I followed the tutorial "A Guide to TF Layers: Building a Convolutional Neural Network" (here is the code: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py).

I adapted the tutorial for my needs, which is hand detection.

As far as I understand, this tutorial creates the estimator (which is a CNN), then does the fitting, and finally, it evaluates the performance of the estimator. Now, my problem is that I want to use the estimator int another file, which is going to be my main program. How do I access the estimator from another file? Do I have to fit the estimator every time I want to use it?? (I hope not)

I was wondering if someone could help me understand how to save the estimator to use it later. (as far as I understand, I cant create a saver with `tf.train.Saver`, because I don't have a session running).

Here is the code from my `train.py` file:

```
def main(unused_argv):

#Load training and eval data (part missing)


# Create the estimator
hand_detector = learn.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="\cnn_model_fn")

# Set up logging for predictions
# Log the values in the "Softmax" tensor with label "probabilities"
tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
    tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

# Train the model
hand_detector.fit(
    x=train_data,
    y=train_labels,
    batch_size=100,
    steps=20000,
    monitors=[logging_hook])

# Configure the accuracy metric for evaluation
metrics = {
    "accuracy":
        learn.MetricSpec(
            metric_fn=tf.metrics.accuracy, prediction_key="classes"),
}

# Evaluate the model and print results
eval_results = hand_detector.evaluate(
    x=eval_data, y=eval_labels, metrics=metrics)
print(eval_results)

# Save the model for later use (part missing!)
```

Answer (score 7):

Almost all real applications of machine learning seek to train a model once and then save it for future uses with new data. Most classifiers spend hours in the training stage and just few seconds in the testing stage, so is fundamental learn how to save successfully a trained model.

I'm going to explain how to export "high level" Tensorflow models (using **export_savedmodel**).
The function **export_savedmodel** requires the argument serving_input_receiver_fn, that is a function without arguments, which defines the input from the model and the predictor. Therefore, you must create your own **serving_input_receiver_fn**, where the model input type match with the model input in the training script, and the predictor input type match with the predictor input in the testing script.
On the other hand, if you create a custom model, you must define the export_outputs,  defined by the function **tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput**, which input is a dictionary that define the name that has to match with the name of the predictor output in the testing script.

For example:

### TRAINING SCRIPT

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None], name='input_tensors')
    receiver_tensors      = {"predictor_inputs": serialized_tf_example}
    feature_spec          = {"words": tf.FixedLenFeature([25],tf.int64)}
    features              = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_spec)
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)
def estimator_spec_for_softmax_classification(logits, labels, mode):
    predicted_classes = tf.argmax(logits, 1)
    if (mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT):
        export_outputs = {'predict_output': tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput({"pred_output_classes": predicted_classes, 'probabilities': tf.nn.softmax(logits)})}
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions={'class': predicted_classes, 'prob': tf.nn.softmax(logits)}, export_outputs=export_outputs) # IMPORTANT!!!
    onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels, 31, 1, 0)
    loss          = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)
    if (mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
        train_op  = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
    eval_metric_ops = {'accuracy': tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=predicted_classes)}
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
def model_custom(features, labels, mode):
    bow_column           = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_identity("words", num_buckets=1000)
    bow_embedding_column = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(bow_column, dimension=50)   
    bow                  = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, feature_columns=[bow_embedding_column])
    logits               = tf.layers.dense(bow, 31, activation=None)
    return estimator_spec_for_softmax_classification(logits=logits, labels=labels, mode=mode)
def main():
    # ...
    # preprocess-> features_train_set and labels_train_set
    # ...
    classifier     = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn = model_custom)
    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={"words": features_train_set}, y=labels_train_set, batch_size=batch_size_param, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)
    classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=100)
    full_model_dir = classifier.export_savedmodel(export_dir_base="C:/models/directory_base", serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

### TESTING SCRIPT

```
def main():
    # ...
    # preprocess-> features_test_set
    # ...
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], full_model_dir)
        predictor   = tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model(full_model_dir)
        model_input = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features( feature={"words": tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=features_test_set)) })) 
        model_input = model_input.SerializeToString()
        output_dict = predictor({"predictor_inputs":[model_input]})
        y_predicted = output_dict["pred_output_classes"][0]
```

(Code tested in Python 3.6.3, Tensorflow 1.4.0)

Comment: How to do it without tf.contrib.predictor? Using input meta graph?

Comment: You really need to put some spacing in your code... ;)

Answer (score 2):

`Estimator` has an `export_savedmodel` member function for that purpose. You will find the docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Estimator#export_savedmodel).

Answer (score 1):

**Update to [David Valenzuela Urrutia's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4268517/david-valenzuela-urrutia) answer(codes)**

David Valenzuela Urrutia's answer was for  Python 3.6.3, Tensorflow 1.4.0 so i thought of updating the answer(code samples) to Tensorflow 2.x because some funtionalities like **tf.Session** is not supported in Tensorflow version 2 so you need to replace it with **tf.compat.v1.Session** for it to work. Visit this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2) to know more about the  changes added to tensorflow version 2

**Training script updated code**

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
   serialized_tf_example = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None], 
       name='input_tensors')
   receiver_tensors      = {"predictor_inputs": serialized_tf_example}
   feature_spec          = {"words": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([25],tf.int64)}
   features              = tf.io.parse_example(serialized=serialized_tf_example, 
       features=feature_spec)
   return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)

def estimator_spec_for_softmax_classification(logits, labels, mode):
   predicted_classes = tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1)
   if (mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT):
      export_outputs = {'predict_output': 
   tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput({"pred_output_classes": predicted_classes, 'probabilities': tf.nn.softmax(logits)})}
   return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions={'class': predicted_classes, 'prob': tf.nn.softmax(logits)}, export_outputs=export_outputs) # IMPORTANT!!!
   onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels, 31, 1, 0)
   loss        =tf.compat.v1.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)
   if (mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN):
       optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
       train_op  = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.compat.v1.train.get_global_step())
       return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
   eval_metric_ops = {'accuracy': tf.compat.v1.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=predicted_classes)}
   return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)

def model_custom(features, labels, mode):
   bow_column           = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_identity("words", num_buckets=1000)
   bow_embedding_column = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(bow_column, dimension=50)   
   bow                  = tf.compat.v1.feature_column.input_layer(features, feature_columns=[bow_embedding_column])
   logits               = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(bow, 31, activation=None)
   return estimator_spec_for_softmax_classification(logits=logits, labels=labels, mode=mode)

def main():
   # ...
   # preprocess-> features_train_set and labels_train_set
   # ...
   classifier     = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn = model_custom)
   train_input_fn = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={"words": features_train_set}, y=labels_train_set, batch_size=batch_size_param, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)
   classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=100)
   full_model_dir = classifier.export_savedmodel(export_dir_base="C:/models/directory_base", serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

**Testing script updated code**

```
def main():
   # ...
   # preprocess-> features_test_set
   # ...
   with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
       tf.compat.v1.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.SERVING], full_model_dir)
       predictor   = tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model(full_model_dir)
       model_input = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features( feature={"words": tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=features_test_set)) })) 
       model_input = model_input.SerializeToString()
       output_dict = predictor({"predictor_inputs":[model_input]})
       y_predicted = output_dict["pred_output_classes"][0]
```